# SaxParser data in ListView with image and text

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an XML file:

```
<root>  
<DATA>  
<NAME>ABC</NAME>  
<IMAGE>http://a2.ak.lscdn.net/imgs/c18196f8-374b-47d2-ad9a-3f2dec64da76/100_q60_.jpg</IMAGE>  
</DATA>  
<DATA>  
<NAME>lmn</NAME>  
<IMAGE>http://w3devadv.liveproj.com/image.php?img=/deals/2011/0905/13152281143500.jpg</IMAGE>  
</DATA>  
</root>
```

In this I'm getting the data of name and I'm not getting image link.

it's showing an error `java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:`

I have edited your first `<IMAGE>` tag it was `<IMAG'>` which is not correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create xml like this

```
   <data name="abc" image="path" ..../>
```

and then do it

you have to draw image at

```
         public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
          String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException
```

method and then store it Vector images = new Vector();
and after get all images path in string and then add images in drawable vector

```
      try {
                images.add(drawable_from_url(atts.getValue("image"), "src"));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

after that setimage background in adapter as
                holder.img1.setBackgroundDrawable(images.get(position));

```
    and drawable method is

        Drawable drawable_from_url(String url, String src_name) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException 
{
    return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), src_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep u must show the code, but u can try this(im use this method in my rss app):

in ur list adapter:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageText_layout, null);
JSONObject jsonImageText = getItem(position);
TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feed_text);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feed_image);
try {

        if (jsonImageText.get("imageLink") != null){

            System.out.println("XXXX Link found!");
            String url = (String) jsonImageText.get("imageLink");
            URL feedImage= new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)feedImage.openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(img);
        }

        Spanned text = (Spanned)jsonImageText.get("text");
        textView.setText(text);
```

create a row viev in new layout(imageText_layout):

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/feed_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/feed_text" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#ffcc00" />
```

load articles in articleList, and buildJsonObject where u:

```
current.put("text", Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
current.put("imageLink", imgLink);
```